# Oracle recursive CTE to check consecutive date rows

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, lead

In trying to make use of a recursive common table expressions and lead analytical function that checks for 'N>1'
consecutive absent_dates but seem to be struggling.

Note I know the employees table isn't included in the query yet to obtain first_name and last_name as I am trying to keep the test case as simple as possible.

Below is my test CASE.

The desired output should be as follows:

```
    EMPLOYEE_ID ABSENT_DATE
    1            14-JUL-21 Jane Doe
    1            15-JUL-21 Jane Doe
    1            30-JUL-21 Jane Doe
    1            31-JUL-21 Jane Doe
    4            22-JUL-21 Mike Jones 
    4            23-JUL-21 Mike Jones 


    Create table employees(
     employee_id NUMBER(6), 
     first_name VARCHAR2(20),
     last_name VARCHAR2(20),
     card_num VARCHAR2(10),
work_days VARCHAR2(7)
    );


     ALTER TABLE employees
             ADD ( CONSTRAINT employees_pk
           PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));

    INSERT INTO employees                   
    (
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    card_num,
    work_days
    )
    WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 1, 'Jane',     'Doe','F123456', 'NYYYYYN'FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'Madison', 'Smith','R33432','NYYYYYN'
   FROM dual UNION ALL 
     SELECT 3, 'Justin',   'Case','C765341','NYYYYYN'
    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Mike',     'Jones','D564311','NYYYYYN' FROM dual  ) 
    SELECT * FROM names;  


     create table absences(
     seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
     employee_id NUMBER(6),
     absent_date DATE,
     constraint absence_chk check (absent_date=trunc(absent_date, 'dd')),
     constraint absence_pk primary key (employee_id, absent_date)
      );



    begin  
      insert into absences values (1,1, date'2021-07-21');  
      insert into absences values (2,4, date'2021-07-22');  
      insert into absences values (3,4, date'2021-07-23');  
      insert into absences values (4,4, date'2021-07-26');  
      insert into absences values (5,1, date'2021-07-30');  
      insert into absences values (6,1, date'2021-07-31');  
      insert into absences values (7,4, date'2021-07-13');  
      insert into absences values (8,1, date'2021-07-14');  
      insert into absences values (9,1, date'2021-07-15');  
      commit;  
    end;
```

-- Different solutions to answer my question

```
     WITH multi_day as (
        -- Uses tabibitosan method to look for sequential groups
         select employee_id
               ,absent_date
                -- tabibitosan... date-row number gives a constant value (in this case date)
                --                            where the dates are sequential
                  ,absent_date-row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by absent_date) as grp
        from   absences
         order by.  employee_id,         absent_date
         )
      select.  m.employee_id
                ,e.first_name
               ,e.last_name
                   ,min(m.absent_date) as start_of_absence
              ,max(m.absent_date) as end_of_absensce
     ,count(*) as days_absent
     from   multi_day m
              join employees e on (e.employee_id = m.employee_id)
      group by m.employee_id
            ,m.grp
             ,e.first_name
             ,e.last_name
      having count(*) > 1
```

order by 1,2;

```
       WITH tab as (
 -- Uses tabibitosan method to look for sequential groups
         select employee_id
               ,absent_date
        -- tabibitosan... date-row number gives a constant value (in this case date)
                --                where the dates are sequential
            ,absent_date-row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by absent_date) as grp
         from   absences
         )
        ,multi_day as (
         select employee_id
               ,absent_date
               ,count(*) over (partition by employee_id, grp) as grp_cnt
         from   tab
         )
       select m.employee_id
             ,e.first_name
             ,e.last_name
             ,m.absent_date
      from   multi_day m
              join employees e on (e.employee_id = m.employee_id)
      where grp_cnt > 1
      order by 1,2;


    WITH      consecutive_absences AS 
    (
            SELECT  a.absent_date,
                           a.employee_id, 
                    e.first_name, 
                    e.last_name, 
            LEAD (a.absent_date) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.employee_id
                             ORDER BY   a.absent_date
                )  AS next_date 
        ,       LAG  (a.absent_date) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.employee_id
                           ORDER BY   a.absent_date
                        )  AS prev_date
         FROM      absences a
                      join employees e on (e.employee_id = a.employee_id)

    ) 
    SELECT       employee_id, 
                     first_name,
             last_name,
               absent_date 
    FROM     consecutive_absences
    ORDER BY employee_id, absent_date;


    SELECT      a.employee_id, a.absent_date
   , e.first_name, e.last_name
    FROM     absences
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE
         (
           PARTITION BY employee_id
           ORDER BY    absent_date
           ALL ROWS PER MATCH
           PATTERN    (frst nxt +)
           DEFINE     nxt AS  absent_date <= PREV (absent_date) + 1
         )  a
    JOIN    employees e  ON e.employee_id = a.employee_id
    ORDER BY employee_id, absent_date
    ;
```

Comment: Please post the expected result and add some more explanation about your result.

Comment: Expected results are in the post where it says expected output should be...

Answer (score 0):

You needn't recursion. Query absences using lead/lag

```
select *
  from (
  select a.*, lead(absent_date) over(partition by employee_id order by absent_date)  nxt, 
    lag(absent_date) over(partition by employee_id order by absent_date) prev
  from absences a
) t
where absent_date = prev + 1 or absent_date = nxt - 1;
```

Then join this to employees.

Comment: Can you  test this query? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  That is not useful.  Do you get an error message, if so what?  Does it not return the correct results?  If so, in what way?  This looks correct to me.

Comment: Probably Oracle wants explicit table alias `a.*` instead of `*` , corrected.

Comment: @Gordon modified original post with several solutions